# I need to update an existing migration by adding only onDelete('cascade');

Tags: laravel, migration, laravel-8

I need your help. Days ago I created the following migration:

*2022_07_28_144638_create_projects_table.php*

Obviously it is not the last because I have created several. Now I have added onDelete ('cascade') on the following line:

`$table-> foreign('client_id') -> references('id') -> on('clients') -> onDelete('cascade');`

so since it was added after now I have to do a migrate on the same migration again.

I need to figure out how to do this. I'm new to Laravel.

Comment: have you ran the migration on a production database or is it all still local?

Comment: @apokryfos it's all local

Comment: Are you asking how to run fresh migrations? [Drop All Tables & Migrate](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#drop-all-tables-migrate)

Comment: Either run them fresh as @brombeer suggests or do `php artisan migrate:rollback` to roll back the last migration and then run `php artisan migrate` again to rerun the latest migration only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in the local environment, you should use the following command.

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

then update migration code

```
$table->foreignId('client_id')->references('id')->constrained('clients')->cascadeOnDelete();
```

then

```
php artisan migrate
```